# Span class in opennlp is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, opennlp

I am new to java opennlp and i am trying to implement a program that extracts city names from a file but i am testing my code on a string first and i get some errors 
the code is

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;

 import main.java.opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.util.Span;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.Tokenizer;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.SimpleTokenizer;
 import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
 import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;

  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

 public class CityFinder {

public String Tokens[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {

    CityFinder toi = new CityFinder();
    String cnt;
    cnt="John is planning to specialize in Electrical Engineering in UC Berkley and  pursue a career with IBM.";
    toi.tokenization(cnt);
    String cities = toi.namefind(toi.Tokens);
    String org = toi.orgfind(toi.Tokens);

    System.out.println("City name is : "+cities);
    System.out.println("organization name is: "+org);

}
    public String namefind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-location.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt); // <-- Here is the Error 
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }
        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;
}

public String orgfind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-organization.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt); // <-- Here is the Error 
        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }

        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;

}
public void tokenization(String tokens) {

    InputStream is;
    TokenizerModel tm;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
        tm = new TokenizerModel(is);
        Tokenizer tz = new TokenizerME(tm);
        Tokens = tz.tokenize(tokens);
        // System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  }
```

I have errors with the following line

```
Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
```

the error is

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from opennlp.tools.util.Span[] to main.java.opennlp.tools.util.Span[]
```

I don't know how to solve it in both locations

Any suggestions....??
thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have imports of `main.java.opennlp.*`? Are those your classes, or do you have two separate copies of the dependency in two different places? There is something wrong with the way your project is set up.

Comment: You're making a lot of questions about OpenNLP that are indicator of the fact that you should put more effort in understanding how the library works, instead of randomly asking questions... at least this is my opinion about the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have imports of `main.java.opennlp.*`? Are those your classes, or do you have two separate copies of the dependency in two different places? There is something wrong with the way your project is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I only changed your imports and works fine:

```
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;           // I've
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;   // changed
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;                       // only these
import opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;     // lines
```

OpenNLP version is 1.5.3